# Named pipe contents are discarded when read only a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, named-pipes

I might be misunderstanding something but should named pipes behave like this?

```
# consumer:
while True:
  queue: int = os.open('pipe', flags=os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
  with os.fdopen(queue, 'rb') as stream:
    readers, _, _ = select([stream], [], [])
    if readers:
      reader = readers.pop()
      contents: bytes = reader.readline().strip()

      if b'quit' == contents:
        break

      print(contents)

# producer:
fd = os.open(pipe, os.O_WRONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
ps = open(fd, 'wb')
for i in range(10):
  ps.write(str(i).encode())
  ps.write(os.linesep.encode())
ps.close()
```

I can see all the data being written to the pipe, and once the file is closed, the select in the consumer picks it up and it starts to read... here's the output:

```
b'0'
```

All the rest of the pipe is discarded like it was never even there. Is this the expected behavior? My expectation would be to print:

```
b'0'
b'1'
...
b'9'
```

I want to use named pipes for inter-process communication. Script A is sending a command to the independent script B, then might send another three. B should pick those command up, and execute them one by one one after the other. Thus the above code. However, only the first is executed and the rest is gone. The commands are not coming like in the above example.

- cmd1+cmd2
- 10sec later
- cmd3
- 5sec later
- cmd4+cmd5+cmd6
- 20sec later
- quit <- at this point Script B terminates

How could I achieve this?

For some magical reason, select hangs the first time.

```
write(hello)
write(newline)
write(world)
flush()
print(hello) <- select hangs
... one eternity later ...
write(how)
write(newline)
write(are)
write(newline)
write(ya)
flush()
print(world) <- This should have been printed also without the new writes...
print(how) <- there were no new writes yet select didn't block as there was new data available for reading
print(are)
print(ya)
```

By adding a timeout of 1 to the select statement, I don't need dummy writes to read the rest of the pipe. Not sure if this is a select limitation, but sure looks fishy, especially from the 2nd time it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update #1**

The problem is that consumer between each select closes and reopens pipe.
It consumed just one line and upon *close* all other data waiting in pipe to be read are gone.

Therefore you should permute `while True` with `fdopen`. Also you should handle EOF properly in consumer (this is where first, additional `while True` comes from). Here is fixed code:

**Consumer**

```
import os, sys
import select

while True:

    print("Opening pipe")
    queue: int = os.open('pipe', flags=os.O_RDONLY)
    with os.fdopen(queue, 'rb') as stream:

        while True:
            readers, _, _ = select.select([stream], [], [])

            if readers:
                reader = readers.pop()

                contents: bytes = reader.readline()
                if contents is b'':
                    print("EOF detected")
                    break

                contents: bytes = contents.strip()
                if b'quit' == contents:
                    sys.exit(0)

                print(contents)
```

**Producer**

Producer lacked of *flush* call:

```
import os

fd = os.open('pipe', os.O_WRONLY)
ps = open(fd, 'wb')
for i in range(10):
    ps.write(str(i).encode())
    ps.write(os.linesep.encode())
    ps.flush()

ps.close()
```

Great help for analyzing your code was running consumer under *strace* which revealed all syscalls and I could notice *close*s between *select*s.

---

*Old outdated answer*

In the line:

```
reader = readers.pop()
```

You get from pipe more content than just first byte.
But then you print out just first byte from what you got.

See that when you add at the end of consumer code another read from reader:

```
contents2: bytes = reader.readline().strip()
print(contents2)
```

You will get:

```
b'0'
b'1'
```

Of course complete code should test how much it got from pipe. Print it and then wait for more data to appear in pipe.

Here is my updated consumer code:

```
import os, sys
import select

while True:
    queue: int = os.open('pipe', flags=os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    with os.fdopen(queue, 'rb') as stream:
        readers, _, _ = select.select([stream], [], [])
        if readers:
            reader = readers.pop()
            while True:
                contents: bytes = reader.readline().strip()
                if contents is b'':
                    break
                if b'quit' == contents:
                    sys.exit(0)

                print(contents)
```

Comment: that's right, but unless I explicitly read that data from the stream using the reader.readline() that data should be picked up in the next iteration. The issue is, unless I place a timeout value on select, for the first time It'll block until a new write occurs. But from this point on forward it'll empty the queue without any new writes. See the updated example in the question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the problem. Now I found that real cause was reopening pipe in each iteration. See update #1 in my answer.